# Set Bitmap to specific size inside imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

Trying to resize a bitmap and set to a specific part of an imageview. The imageview is square and I wish to have the bitmap in the bottom right corner. Width to be 10% of imageview and height to be 30%.

```
int w = imageview.getWidth();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vertical_bar_green);
imageview.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, w/10, w*30/100, false));
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

The result is the bitmap is the full height of the imageview and the width is much larger.

How can I set specific points to place the bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [END](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#END) (the matrix used by `FIT_END`).

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but
>   will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. **At least one axis
>   (X or Y) will fit exactly.** END aligns the result to the right and
>   bottom edges of dst.

You will probable want to use a custom matrix for this, probably built with [`setRectToRect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit%29).

For example:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
RectF from = new RectF(0, 0, bm.getIntrinsicWidth(), bm.getIntrinsicHeight());
RectF to = new RectF(view.getWidth() * 0.9, view.getHeight() * 0.7, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
matrix.setRectToRect(from, to, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);

view.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

(I'm not sure if you wanted to keep the original proportions or not, if you want it then use `FIT_END` for `setRectToRect()`).